# Отслеживание одинаковых процессов

Tags: c#

В своей программе мне надо запускать одно и то же приложение например так:

```
    Process.Start("Application.exe","-param");
```

Аналогичных процессов я запускаю множество с разными параметрами. Иногда они подвисают. Хотелось бы их в своей программе закрывать через определенный промежуток времени, не трогая остальные процессы. Но как в приложении распознать подвисшие процессы? Можно было бы создать много разных приложений (App1.exe, App2.exe...) и их по очереди запускать, но есть какое нибудь более изящное решение?

Comment: Вобщем пока никто не ответил решила вот так: перед запуском копирую файл exe и называю его какждый раз по новому и потом отслеживаю его в диспетчере задач. Если что kill
Но хочу что бы не копировать файл, а именно запускать а в процессах он назывался так как я хочу